# How to create and set primitive in Golang using reflect

Tags: go, reflection

I want to test how my function `setFieldValue()` works.

```
func main() {

    value := uint64(0x36)
    resType := reflect.TypeOf(uint8(0))
    expectedRes := uint8(0x36)

    res := uint8(0)
    setFieldValue(reflect.ValueOf(&res).Elem(), resType.Kind(), value)

    if res == expectedRes {
        fmt.Println("voila")
    } else {
        fmt.Println("nuts")
    }
}

func setFieldValue(field reflect.Value, fieldKind reflect.Kind, fieldValue uint64) {
    switch fieldKind {
    case reflect.Uint8:
        field.SetUint(fieldValue)
    }
}
```

But I don't want `res` variable also has type `TypeOf(uint8(0))`. If I create res as

```
        res := reflect.New(resType)
        setFieldValue(res, resType.Kind(), value)
```

it doesn't work because res is unaddressable.

What is the correct way to create variable using reflect and then to set its value in some func?

Or how can I get the instance of newly created variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`reflect.New` returns a `reflect.Value` that represents a *pointer*, the pointer itself is not addressable and it's also *not* what you want to set the value to. What's addressable however is the value to which the pointer points and that's also what you *want* to set the provided value.

You can use `res.Elem()` to dereference the pointer.

```
func main() {
    value := uint64(0x36)
    resType := reflect.TypeOf(uint8(0))
    expectedRes := uint8(0x36)

    res := reflect.New(resType)
    setFieldValue(res.Elem(), resType.Kind(), value)

    if res.Elem().Interface() == expectedRes {
        fmt.Println("voila")
    } else {
        fmt.Println("nuts")
    }
}
```